# Add CSS to form field in django template

Tags: python, html, css, django, twitter-bootstrap

I want to use bootstrap on django form. To do so I need to add `.form-control` class to each field. My workaround is:

```py
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(SomeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    for field in self.fields:
        self.fields[field].widget.attrs = {
            'class': 'form-control'
        }
```

```html
{% for field in form %}
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ field.label_tag }}
        {{ field }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

But I believe it's wrong to put CSS in python code (if I would want to use another CSS framework, I would have to change form class). How can I move the class to template? I would not like to use crispy not to be bound to bootstrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a custom template tag for adding a class, see more information [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-template-tags/)

You will have to create a new module inside the templatetags directory:

```
myapp/
    __init__.py
    models.py
    templatetags/
        __init__.py
        extra_filters.py <-- Name it as you prefer
    views.py
    forms.py
```

The content of your extra_filters.py module can be something like this:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()


@register.filter(name='addclass')
def addclass(field, myclass):
    return field.as_widget(attrs={"class": myclass})
```

Now in your template, load the new filter and use it as follows:

```
{% load extra_filters %}

{% for field in form %}
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ field.label_tag }}
        {{ field|addclass:"form-control" }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `form-control` css class to the widgets.

The form class is the access point of the input tags through widgets. By changing the widget attr from the constructor method in `form.Form`

```
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    
        for field in self.visible_fields():
            field.field.widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control'})
```